# Why am I getting this `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound. (Couldn't find 'id') ` error from POST requests in my Rails API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Some context. I am creating an API that is contacted by an external server. This external server contacts the API with  POST requests to the endpoint `/vehicles` with a unique id number. The request body has the format `{ "id": “some_string_here” }`. My API stores these in the db. After the vehicles have been created the external server then makes POST requests with the endpoint `vehicles/:id/locations` with the request body looking something like this `{ "lat": 10.0, "lng": 20.0, "at": "2019-09-01T12:00:00Z" }` - adding lat lng coordinates and a time stamp to each vehicle periodically (to update the vehicle's location).

I have been able to set up my API with `vehicles` and `locations` controllers and when I start the external server the vehicles are stored successfully. The problem I have is when the server then starts to send requests to add locations to each vehicle. In the console I get the message:

```
Processing by LocationsController#create as HTML

  Parameters: {"lat"=>52.44381, "lng"=>13.47686, "at"=>"2019-07-28T16:56:45.311Z", "vehicle_id"=>"d759fc35-b25c-4877-8e40-9b0104447b31", "location"=>{"lat"=>52.44381, "lng"=>13.47686, "at"=>"2019-07-28T16:56:45.311Z"}}
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Vehicle with 'id'=d6880741-ae7f-4741-aa04-950b0a1e2d3b):
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.

app/controllers/locations_controller.rb:9:in `create'
  Vehicle Load (38.2ms)  SELECT  "vehicles".* FROM "vehicles" WHERE "vehicles"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/locations_controller.rb:9
Completed 404 Not Found in 50ms (ActiveRecord: 38.2ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Vehicle with 'id'=d759fc35-b25c-4877-8e40-9b0104447b31):
```

The problem might have something to do with the fact that the requests to store a vehicle have `id` as the key in the body (the same name as the default primary key column name). This meant that I had to create a new column for the vehicle id that the server is passing and then add this code in my controller to change the params hash:

```
def vehicle_params
  params[:vehicle][:unique_id] = params[:vehicle].delete(:id)
end
```

This meant that vehicles were stored correctly, however it may (or may not) be the reason why I am getting the error message described above. Any ideas how I can fix this? My relevant code is below.

vehicles_controller.rb

```
class VehiclesController < ApplicationController
...
  def create
    @vehicle = Vehicle.new(vehicle_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @vehicle.save
        format.json { render status: :created, location: @vehicle }
      else
        format.json { render json: @vehicle.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def vehicle_params
      # swap id column value with unique_id to avoid conflict with primary key
      params[:vehicle][:unique_id] = params[:vehicle].delete(:id)
      params.require(:vehicle).permit(:unique_id)
    end
end
```

locations_controller.rb

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
...
  def create
    @vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:vehicle_id])
    @location = @vehicle.locations.new(location_params)


    respond_to do |format|
      if @location.save
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @vehicle }
      else
        format.json { render json: @location.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def location_params
      params.require(:location).permit(:lat, :lng, :at, :vehicle_id)
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :vehicles do
    resources :locations
  end
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_07_27_224818) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.float "lat"
    t.float "lng"
    t.datetime "at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "vehicle_id"
  end

  create_table "vehicles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "unique_id"
  end
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In Rails console, `Vehicle.find("d6880741-ae7f-4741-aa04-950b0a1e2d3b")` - does it exist?

Comment: @JoshBrody Nope `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Vehicle with 'id'=d6880741-ae7f-4741-aa04-950b0a1e2d3b)`

Comment: There's your issue then. You need to figure out what resource ID that really is.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the string `d6880741-ae7f- ....` is supposed to correspond to the `unique_id` column on vehicles. In which case you would use

```
@vehicle = Vehicle.find_by!(unique_id: params[:vehicle_id])
```

The `id` column is an int, and `params[:vehicle_id]` is a string ... thus `Vehicle.find(params[:vehicle_id])` would always raise a "not found" error, which is the behavior you're seeing.

Note that `find` and `find_by!` will raise an error if the record is not found. If you don't want to have this happen, you can use `find_by` (without the exclamation point) - it just returns nil if the record is not found. But you will have to change your code to account for the possibility that `@vehicle` is nil.

Comment: thanks for the reply - much appreciated. I tried your code and it gave me the following error in the console: `ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  ↳ app/controllers/locations_controller.rb:14
  
Completed 406 Not Acceptable`

Comment: You're not using the `respond_do to |format|` block correctly. Google a bit on how that works.

Comment: Yeah, I don't really get it. I'm having a hard time understanding it tbh. The vehicles are saving but not the locations.

Comment: This seems like two issues you're trying to solve at the same time. One is the "unknown error" format - does the request you're sending have content-type = 'application/json'? The other is the model error. You can print out `@location.errors` in your `else` block to see what that is.

Comment: `@location.errors` gives me `undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: I meant to put it in location controller's `else` block (in `def create`)

Comment: Ah, sorry. That gives `<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007f5fa44b71b0>
No template found for LocationsController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 67ms (ActiveRecord: 7.7ms)`

Comment: I don't know, Steve. We're straying away from the original question here, unfortunately I can't solve everything in one place. Might be worth posting a new question.